# Using bootstrap, how do I add a margin to a div but only in md or smaller?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have these two div's:

```
<div class="col col-md-8">
    <input id="CampaignName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Campaign Name">
</div>
<div class="col col-md-2">
    <button id="createCampaign" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Create Campaign</button>
</div>
```

The are fine in lg, but when the screen collapses to size md or smaller, then the button is below the textbox, and they hug each other too tightly.

I'd like to add some margin between them, but NOT if the screen is lg.

Comment: Search for media queries - you can then target css depending on the size of the device, which is what `col-md-*` etc does anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use predefined bootstrap classes for that - just insert additional `div` between input and button. and make this `div` hidden for `lg`-viewport.

And you can vary its height as you wish.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col col-md-8">
    <input id="CampaignName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Campaign Name">
 </div>

 <div class="hidden-lg hidden-md" style="height: 20px;"></div>

 <div class="col col-md-2">
      <button id="createCampaign" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Create Campaign</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: This is the simplest of all answers.  Thanks!

Comment: I agree, it is the simplest although not the more efficient. div will be created and then hidden using a very small amount of memory on the process.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to:

Use **media-queries** to add a custom margin between the elements when the screen size is lower than 1200px and greater than 992px *refer for more information:* (https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-the-bootstrap-3-grid-system)

Example:

```
/* Greater than 992px, and less than 1200px */
@media (max-width:1200px) and (min-width:992px) {
    #CampaignName {
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use custom css and plus media queries (queries depend on the version of bootstrap you are using.)
Add a class and and specify the margin you wish to have in your css.

example

```
<div class="col col-md-8 with-margin-sm">
    <input id="CampaignName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Campaign Name">
</div>
<div class="col col-md-2 with-margin-sm">
    <button id="createCampaign" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Create Campaign</button>
</div>
```

And then the css

```
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
 .with-margin-sm{
    margin: 0 2px 0 2px;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to follow the same sizes as Bootstrap you'd do something like this where ### is a number of pixels:

```
@media (max-width: ###px) {
  .col {
    margin: whatever;
  }
}
```

Bootstrap's default grid (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) would use 0, 768, 992, & 1200 for these sizes. So if you wanted to apply the css to JUST the `md` size and not bigger or smaller, you'd want 992 to 1199. Or the following:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .col {
    margin: whatever;
  }
}
```